# Bulk insert issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

During a bulk insert from a csv file a row in the file has `00000100008` value, both source (from which csv file is created) and the destination *`temptable`* has same field (char(11)).

When I try to insert I got the following error:

```
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 1 (fieldname)
```

If I remove the leading 0s and change this value to `100008` in csv file and then bulk insert, the destination table *`temptable`* shows `'++  100008` as inserted value. Why is that? How I can cope with value without leading double plus signs?

Here is the script:

```
BULK
INSERT temptable
FROM 'c:\TestFile.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

**Edit:** Some sample records from csv file.

```
100008,111122223333,Mr,ForeName1,SurName1,1 Test Lane,London,NULL,NULL,NULL,wd25 123,test@email.com.com,NULL
322,910315715845,Ms,G,Dally,17 Elsie Street,NULL,NULL,GOOLE,NULL,DN146DU,test1@email1.com,
323,910517288401,Mrs,G,Tom,2 White Mead,NULL,NULL,YEOVIL,NULL,BA213RS,test3@tmail2.com,
```

Comment: How are you viewing and editting the csv file?  Open it in Notepad++ or Programmers Notepad or similar, then you can see *exactly* what is in that file *(without Excel changing the appearance of the data for you, for example)*.

Comment: Dems, I am viewing csv file with windows notepad.

Comment: Is the value delimited with single quotes? (Can you post the exact contents of the file?)

Comment: Philip, records are delimited with single quote. some sample records added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is that the file was saved on a Unix system and that you may have incompatibilities with the different style line breaks.
My first advice would be to analyze the text file using a hex editor to try to determine what character is getting put there.

++ 100008 basically means - Row format is inconsistent with page header. To solve this problem  Run dbcc checktable.

I hope that this is going to help you.

Regards,

Comment: file is saved on windows. I have run the dbcc checktable command for the table, but it didn't return any error.